# Reinstalled windows, apache will not start

Tags: apache-2.2, xampp

Had to reinstall most of the stuff on my machine, but I had xampp on a separate drive. I started up the control panel and hit start on the apache service, but it will not start.

Here is the error I am receiving. I'm a little confused as to what is happening since I never touched anything on in the xampp folder.

```
[Tue Nov 29 21:45:33 2011] [error] VirtualHost _default_:443 -- mixing * ports and
non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with 
undefined results

(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
normally permitted.  : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443 
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates that something else is listening on port 443 on your system. Is it possible that an instance is already running? Either way, to see what is going on have a look at netstat -ano, and see which pid is bound to port 443.